# Problem with embeded document query, when building query dynamically

Tags: mongoid

I'm trying to dynamically build a query where one can query an embedded document but it fails.

If I, however, copy the content of the query and try it works.

```
0> query
=> {:"properties.account_id"=>"5bd046d21d41c82e7c000004"}

0> Collection.where(query).to_a
=> []

0> Collection.where({:"properties.account_id"=>"5bd046d21d41c82e7c000004"}).to_a
=> [#<Collection _id: 5bd046d21d41c82e7c000006, created_at: 2018-10-24 10:17:54 UTC, updated_at: 2018-10-24 10:17:54 UTC, properties: {"account_id"=>"5bd046d21d41c82e7c000004"}>]

0> Collection.where(:"properties.account_id"=>"5bd046d21d41c82e7c000004").to_a
=> [#<Collection _id: 5bd046d21d41c82e7c000006, created_at: 2018-10-24 10:17:54 UTC, updated_at: 2018-10-24 10:17:54 UTC, properties: {"account_id"=>"5bd046d21d41c82e7c000004"}>]
```

And I have tried without colon

```
0> query
=> {"properties.account_id"=>"5bd049651d41c872d2000004"}

0> Collection.where(query).to_a
=> []

0> Collection.where({"properties.account_id"=>"5bd049651d41c872d2000004"}).to_a
=> [#<Collection _id: 5bd049651d41c872d2000006, created_at: 2018-10-24 10:28:53 UTC, updated_at: 2018-10-24 10:28:53 UTC, properties: {"account_id"=>"5bd049651d41c872d2000004"}>]
```

The explain data seems fine as well

```
{
  "queryPlanner" => {
    "plannerVersion" => 1, "namespace" => "db_testing.coll_test", "indexFilterSet" => false, "parsedQuery" => {
      "properties.account_id" => {
        "$eq" => "5bd04bf91d41c8d153000004"
      }
    }, "winningPlan" => {
      "stage" => "COLLSCAN", "filter" => {
        "properties.account_id" => {
          "$eq" => "5bd04bf91d41c8d153000004"
        }
      }, "direction" => "forward"
    }, "rejectedPlans" => []
  }, "executionStats" => {
    "executionSuccess" => true, "nReturned" => 0, "executionTimeMillis" => 1, "totalKeysExamined" => 0, "totalDocsExamined" => 2, "executionStages" => {
      "stage" => "COLLSCAN", "filter" => {
        "properties.account_id" => {
          "$eq" => "5bd04bf91d41c8d153000004"
        }
      }, "nReturned" => 0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate" => 0, "works" => 4, "advanced" => 0, "needTime" => 3, "needFetch" => 0, "saveState" => 0, "restoreState" => 0, "isEOF" => 1, "invalidates" => 0, "direction" => "forward", "docsExamined" => 2
    }, "allPlansExecution" => []
  }, "serverInfo" => {
    "host" => "ubuntu", "port" => 27017, "version" => "3.0.15", "gitVersion" => "b8ff507269c382bc100fc52f75f48d54cd42ec3b"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I found a solution for my problem, just by adding .to_s on the value fixed the problem.

    params[:properties].each { |k, v| query.merge!("properties.#{k}" => v.to_s) } if params[:properties]

Regards

Comment: You should post the comment as an answer